# Connecting multiple Huawei e3372h LTE modems to get multiple internet connections

Tags: networking, proxy, internet-connection, modem

**My goal:**

-Setup about 15 LTE/4G USB modems (Huawei e3372h), connected to PC with Windows 10 via USB hub and providing 15 separate internet connections

-Use Wingate program for creating 15 proxy services that will be accessible via the PC with USB hub and modem sticks

**What I am struggling with:**

-When I put two or more modems into PC, then the internet stops working

-when I turn of DHCP and set IP to for example 192.168.8.2 (dečfault is 192.168.8.2) in Huawei Hilink controlo app for the modem, I cannot get back into the app as the connections time out

-I guess I just have to set up manual IP settings in windows for the modem, but I dont know what IPs to set

Question: **How should I set up Huawei 4G modems to have them work all at the same time?**

Comment: I have a similar (but different model) HUAWEI Modem here (LTE E8372).  You cannot put 2 in the same computer. You need to set the second one up in a different computer. Otherwise use a Cellular Hotspot to which you can attach a router.

Comment: I have seen setups people use that can do it, its just about setting the right values up